# Does yasnippet support alternative placeholders?

Tags: yasnippet

Consider sample below:

```
SERVER-1
[connection] 192.168.0.1 success
[connection] 192.168.0.2 failed
[disconnect] 192.168.0.3 pending
[connection] 192.168.0.4 success
```

but `[${1:connection}] ${2:192.168.0.${3:1}} ${4:success}` only work for one placeholder (doesn't support alternative placeholders),

Does ya-snippet support syntax like `${1:connection OR disconnect}` to give more alternative placeholders? (that's when you cursor is in placeholder, you hit `tab` then give you next placeholder until the last, yeah this is inefficient when you have list of choices, so consider the alternative implement below instead...)

or maybe integrate elisp powerful function like

`${1:$$(popup-prompt '("connection" "disconnect"))}` prompt for completion, i guess this function exist...

Comment: `yas-choose-value` perhaps?

Comment: yeah, that's what i want, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Choosing fields value from a list and other tricks](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-8):

> As mentioned, the field transformation is invoked just after you enter
>   the field, and with some useful variables bound, notably
>   `yas-modified-p` and `yas-moving-away-p`. Because of this feature you can
>   place a transformation in the primary field that lets you select
>   default values for it.
>
> The function `yas-choose-value` does this work for you. For example:
>
> ```
> <div align="${2:$$(yas-choose-value '("right" "center" "left"))}">  
>   $0
> </div>
> ```
>
> See the definition of `yas-choose-value` to see how it was written using the two variables.